# discrete and continuous scales on same axis in facet_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2, grid-layout, facet

I want to use `facet_grid` in `ggplot2` to produce two graphs with continuous and discrete scales on the same axis - essentially my vector `fac` has a numeric part and a factor part.

```
toy=data.frame(type=xc("f f f f i i i i"),fac=c(letters[1:4],1:3,40))
ggplot(toy,aes(x=ifelse(type=="f",fac,as.numeric((fac)))))+
   geom_bar()+facet_grid(.~type,scales="free")
```

But it doesn't work because `ggplot` forces both scales to be discrete.
 [image]

As you can see from the equal spacing of 1,2,3,40 on the right-hand plot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two types of data in one column is not the best way to represent data.

Changed sample data for column `fac` to get better representation.

```
toy=data.frame(type=c("f", "f","f", "f", "i", "i", "i", "i"),fac=c(letters[1:4],1,5,7,40))
```

To get an unequal spaces for numeric values you can make two `geom_bar()` call, each for separate type (using `subset=`). For letters use data as they are but for numeric data convert `fac` values to character and then to numeric. `facet_grid()` will ensure that you have two plots. `scale_x_discrete()` will work for both facets - you just have to provide desired `breaks=` values.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)    
ggplot(data=toy)+
  geom_bar(subset=.(type=="f"),aes(x=fac),width=0.2)+
  geom_bar(subset=.(type=="i"),aes(x=as.numeric(as.character(fac))))+
  facet_grid(.~type,scales="free") + 
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=c("a","b","c","d",1,5,7,40))
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice, thanks! I would never have thought that `scale_x_discrete(breaks=c("a","b","c","d",1,5,7,40))` would provide a scale with the correct distances.

Comment: Correct distances are made subseting data and converting them. scale_x_discrete() is just used to set labels. You can try the code without scale function and see the result.